# Trivial question about interpreting probability

Tags: probability

Please excuse the trivial nature of this question but I can't convince myself of the correct answer.

Suppose there are two events $A$ and $B$ with probabilities:

$p(A)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $p(B)=\frac{2}{9}$

The question is, "How much more likely is event $A$ than $B$?"

My initial answer was $A$ was $1.5$ times more likely than $B$.
Whilst discussing the problem with the problem with a friend they suggested the $A$ was $\frac{1}{9}$ more likely than $B$.

We both agreed that saying $1.5$ times more likely made sense mathematically and is a natural phrase to use in English.  The discussion arose as to whether the $\frac{1}{9}$ more sentence was just unusual grammar or hides some error mathematically?

My feeling is that it is incorrect somehow but can't quite say why.

Any comments would be gratefully received.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Fax answer was brought up about possible ambiguity in our discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's just two ways of saying the same thing and both are correct. why? here's why:

- you explicitly used the word "times": "*...My initial answer was A was 1.5 **times** more likely than B...*"
- when expressing difference "times" was not used: "*...A was 1/9 **[no use of times]** more likely than B...*"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Fax point about ambiguity came up in our discussions.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitively unusual grammar. While the statement is ambiguous because it is not clear whether you are referring to $\frac 19$ of $1$ or $\frac 19$ of $B$, the latter is assumed in common usage.

The ambiguity is more clear with percentages: If your wallet contains 20% of your salary, and you win 10% more on a scratch ticket, do you now have 30% or 22% of your salary?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you say the sentence is not clear enough to infer the meaning?

Comment: Yes. You could instead say something like "A is more likely than B by P equals one-ninth", which would make it a little more clear. I'm also unsure whether it makes any sense at all if A and B are independent events.

Comment: As it happens they were independent. One event was picking a yellow cube from one containing a yellow and two reds at random. The other was picking a 9 or 10 from cards with the numbers 2 to 10 on them.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to what? All the events or only the cases when A and B occur?
The probability of A is 1/9 higher to occur when you compare the events of A to B when you look at the total number of events. If you compare only the events that include A or B, than the answer is 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would never say that $A$ was $1/9$ was more likely than $B$, because I think the general interpretation of that would be $P(A) = (10/9) P(B)$.  I might say something like the probability of $A$ is $1/9$ greater than the probability of $B$, or (even better) the probability of $A$ is greater than the probability of $B$ by $1/9$ (cf. "greater than $\ldots$ by a *factor* of $10/9$").

I would also not say $A$ was $1.5$ times more likely than $B$; I would say that $A$ is $1.5$ times *as* likely as $B$.  "More likely" leaves it unclear whether $A$ is $1.5$ times or $2.5$ times as likely as $B$—the same problem that results from expressions such as "Pat's fund is $150$ percent larger than Mark's fund."